# Accessing MONITORINFOEX values in Visual C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm perplexed trying to retrieve `MONITORINFOEX` values. I tried:

```
typedef struct tagMONITORINFO {
    DWORD cbSize;
    RECT  rcMonitor;
    RECT  rcWork;
    DWORD dwFlags;
} MONITORINFO, *LPMONITORINFO;
typedef struct tagMONITORINFOEX {
    CHAR       szDevice[CCHDEVICENAME];
    MONITORINFO tagMONITORINFO;
} MONITORINFOEX, *LPMONITORINFOEX;
MONITORINFOEX miea;
miea.tagMONITORINFO.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFOEX);
GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, (&miea));
```

to no avail. I modified the last line to:

```
GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, ((LPMONITORINFO) &miea));
```

again, no luck. I get compiler messages about the 2nd parameter of `GetMonitorInfo`.

Comment: Why do you redefine the structures? Why not include the proper Windows header files and use the standard structures? And *what* is your problem with the code you show? Do you get build errors? Runtime errors or crashes? Invalid results?

Comment: _I get compiler messages about the 2nd parameter of GetMonitorInfo._ Add the error messages to the question.

Comment: your definition of `MONITORINFOEX` is wrong. and anyway - it defined in *MultiMon.h* - `struct tagMONITORINFOEXA : public tagMONITORINFO
{
    CHAR        szDevice[CCHDEVICENAME];
} MONITORINFOEXA, *LPMONITORINFOEXA;`

Comment: @som: It's only a redefinition, if you actually include the header files that define the structures. While common, there are reasons why you'd want to define those structures yourself. A library may not want to `#include <Windows.h>`, and rather define what it needs. [C++/WinRT](http://aka.ms/cppwinrt) recently removed the dependency on *Windows.h*, for example.

Comment: @IInspectable It would be a redefinition if the structures were a byte-by-byte, character by character, exact duplicate. Otherwise it's *undefined behavior* as it breaks the one definition rule. And in this case it apparently *isn't* exact duplicates.

Comment: @som: We don't know, *how* it breaks, hence we don't know, what's causing it either. As you noted in your first comment already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code you have shown you try to define `struct`s that are part of WinAPI yourself. Don't do that, there is no need to. Include the appropriate header files instead.

Simple sample:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    // just a cheap way to get a handle
    auto monitor{ MonitorFromWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST) };

    MONITORINFOEXW miex{ sizeof miex };  // set cbSize member
    if (!GetMonitorInfoW(monitor, &miex)) {
        std::cerr << "GetMonitorInfo() failed :(\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::wcout << miex.szDevice << ": "
               << miex.rcMonitor.right  - miex.rcMonitor.left << " x "
               << miex.rcMonitor.bottom - miex.rcMonitor.top  << '\n';
}
```

#### Sample output:

```
\\.\DISPLAY1: 2560 x 1440
```

Comment: not need `static_cast<LPMONITORINFO>(&miex)` can simply use `&miex` because `MONITORINFOEXW : public MONITORINFO`

Comment: @RbMm Right. Was a little surprised though since most WinAPI structs don't use inheritance.

Comment: The winapi targets the C language, not C++.  I think the core advice is that the OP must not declare the structs by himself, that's not going to end well since these identifiers are macros and not structs.  Be sure to point that out.

Comment: @HansPassant "The winapi targets the C language, not C++." thats why i was surprised.

Comment: `MONITORINFOEX` deriving from `MONITORINFO` is wrapped in a `#ifdef __cplusplus` preprocessor guard. The C implementation uses composition, where `MONITORINFO` is the first member of `MONITORINFOEX`. The entirety of the Windows API (and Windows Runtime) is still exposed as a C interface, with occasional convenience wrappers and declarations in C++.